# Unexpected end of input in parsec

Tags: haskell, parsec

I want to parse a file like this:

```
66:3 3:4
329:2 
101:3 
495:4 
55:5 
268:5 
267:2 
242:4 
262:1 
861:1
```

My code is like the following:

```
getTestData :: String -> IO [[(Int, Int)]]
getTestData name = do
    --res <- parseFromFile testData (name ++ ".test")
    fc <- readFile (name ++ ".test")
    let res = parse testData "test data" fc
    case res of
        Left e -> error $ show e-- "test data parse eror."
        Right ts -> return ts

eol = char '\n'
testData = endBy line eol
--testData = many line
testTuple = do
    i <- natural
    colon
    r <- natural
    return (fromIntegral i:: Int, fromIntegral r:: Int)

line = sepBy testTuple whiteSpace
```

But when run, it throw an exception:

```
ts <- getTestData "data" 
*** Exception: "test data" (line 11, column 1):
unexpected end of input
expecting natural or "\n"
```

I don't understand, why it said line 11, when my data.test file only has 10 lines. So I failed to fix this problem after several tries.

Comment: You're finding end-of-file rather than end-of-line. Note also that Parsec's default `whiteSpace` combinator used in the `line` parser consumes newlines  so you don't want `testData` to use `eol` as an `endBy` condition. Maybe using `testData = many1 line` would work, but in general you have to be quite careful about whitespace handling even for simple formats. Parsec was built for parsing programming languages rather than line oriented data files, so it sees all whitespace as the same thing rather than distinguishing newlines or whatever.

Comment: when use many, it complains like that: *** Exception: Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Prim.many: combinator 'many' is applied to a parser that accepts an empty string.

Comment: What if you turn `line` into `line = sepBy1 testTuple whiteSpace` ? (although this is going down a dodgy track regarding whitespace)

Comment: Change to sep1 yields the same problem. And I don't think it's related to the exception. I wonder if the culprit is "line 11" where my file has only 10 line.

Comment: Actually I was wrong to suggest `line = sepBy1 testTuple whiteSpace` - you can't write a line oriented parser using `whiteSpace`. In this case, because you want a line oriented parser and your format is otherwise simple, you are better off making primitive parsers with `Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Char` rather than using token parsers from `Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Token`. You will need to write your own version of `natural` though.

Comment: I had change whiteSpace to many (char ' '), but that didn't help.

Comment: That won't help - the problem is that `natural` and `colon` consume any trailing white-space, so the testTuple parser has already consumed any newlines. For a white space sensitive parser you need to implement your own versions of the parsers in `Text.Parsec.Token`.

Answer (score 5):

My best guess is that `whiteSpace` in `line` is consuming the newlines.  So your whole file is being parsed by a single `line` parser, and the `eol` parser never gets a chance to get its hands on a `"\n"`.  Try replacing `whiteSpace` with `many (char ' ')` and see if that helps.

Comment: When change whiteSpace to many (char ' '), it raise this similar exception:*** Exception: "test data" (line 11, column 1):
unexpected end of input
expecting " ", natural or "\n"

Comment: I guess the parser find a eof in line 11, so as to think it unexpected.

Answer (score 4):

This is a working implementation using primitive char parsers rather than token parsers. Note - it's more robust not to use whitespace as a separator, but to drop it if it exists. The bits where I've used one line do-notation are a lot neater if you use `(<*)` from Applicative.

```
{-# OPTIONS -Wall #-}

module ParsecWhite where

import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec

import Data.Char

main = getTestData "sample"

getTestData :: String -> IO [[(Int, Int)]]
getTestData name = do
    --res <- parseFromFile testData (name ++ ".test")
    fc <- readFile (name ++ ".test")
    let res = parse testData "test data" fc
    case res of
        Left e -> error $ show e -- "test data parse eror."
        Right ts -> return ts

testData :: Parser [[(Int,Int)]]
testData = input


input :: Parser [[(Int,Int)]]
input = many (do { a <- line; newline; return a })
     <?> "input"

line :: Parser [(Int,Int)]
line = many (do { a <- testTuple; softWhite; return a})  <?> "line"

testTuple :: Parser (Int,Int)
testTuple = do
    i <- natural
    colon
    r <- natural
    return (i,r)
  <?> "testTuple"

softWhite :: Parser ()
softWhite = many (oneOf " \t") >> return ()

colon :: Parser () 
colon = char ':' >> return ()

natural :: Parser Int
natural = fmap (post 0) $ many1 digit
  where
    post ac []     = (ac * 10) 
    post ac [x]    = (ac * 10) + digitToInt x
    post ac (x:xs) = post ((ac * 10) + digitToInt x) xs
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works well. I rewrite my code according to yours, and really found out that all of natural, whiteSpace and line in my original code need to change to yours to make it work.

Comment: I also figure out why my original 'line' definition didn't work. Because my test file has trailing spaces, the parser guess there will be other tuples.

Answer (score 1):

I bet you are missing a newline at the end of the last line.
For parsing a complete line it should be "861:1\n" but it probably is "861:1EOF".
So I think your parser correctly identifies your input to be incorrect.

Comment: *Main> readFile "data.test" 
"66:3 3:4\n329:2 \n101:3 \n495:4 \n55:5 \n268:5 \n267:2 \n242:4 \n262:1 \n861:1 \n"
So it's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

actually, i found you can use whiteSpace (to easily ignore multi-line block comments, for example), while still being line-oriented.  just include this parser when you want newlines.

```
col (== 1) "only matches beginning of line"

col pred errStr = do
  c <- sourceColumn <$> getPosition
  if pred c then return ()
            else unexpected errStr
```